# Performing Single Row Arithmetic on 2D Vector to find Reduced Row Form C++

Tags: c++, matrix, vector, linear-algebra, 2d-vector

So for AC circuits, you sometimes have to solve linear systems with complex numbers and I'm making a quick and dirty program to do it for me. I've written the code that will create a matrix (2D vector) of user-defined size and input, I just can't figure out how to get it to perform the arithmetic row by row. I tried iterating through the first row and multiplying each element by 1/matrix[1][1] however it gives me an error message saying I cannot perform the operation. Here's the code I have so far for the purpose I described above. I'm relatively new to c++ and coding as a whole so there may be a simple way to do it I'm missing.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <complex>

using namespace std;
int main() 
{

    int rows;
    int columns;
    cout << "Enter number of rows: " << endl;
    cin >> rows;
    cout << "Enter number of columns: " << endl;
    cin >> columns;

    vector<vector<complex<double> > > matrix(rows, vector<complex<double> > (columns));
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        k++;
        cout << "Enter row " << k << ": " << endl;
            
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
        {
            complex<double> input;
            cin >> input;
            matrix[i][j] = input;
        }

    }

    for (int g = 0; g < rows; g++)
    {
        for (int h = 0; h < columns; h++)
        {
            cout << matrix[g][h] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    
for (int b = 0; b < columns; b++) {
        matrix[1][1] = a;
        matrix[1][b] = (matrix[1][b]) * (1 / a)

    }
    return 0;
}`
```

Comment: Can you show the code that gives you the error as well as the complete error message?

Comment: I added the for loop that's giving me trouble. Its not an error message but visual studio has the red underline thing underneath the division symbol where I try to perform the operation (1 / a).

Answer (score 1):

You have to manually convert them to complex, or match it's type

i.e.

```
std::complex<double> x(1, 2); // x = 1.0 + 2.0i

// x * 3 Error!, 3 is int
auto y = x * std::complex<double>(3, 0); // works! y = 3.0 + 6.0i
auto z = x * 3.0
```

Comment: Well, not really. There *are* overloads of the [math operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/operator_arith3) accepting complex and scalar types, but the [types have to match](https://godbolt.org/z/rT5Tzx).

Answer (score 1):

> I tried iterating through the first row and multiplying each element by `1/matrix[1][1]` however it gives me an error message saying I cannot perform the operation.

If `matrix` is declared as

```
vector<vector<complex<double> > > matrix(rows, vector<complex<double> > (columns));
```

The type of its elements is `std::complex<double>`, so that the underlying type is `double`.

There are overloads of the binary [math operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/operator_arith3) accepting complex and scalar types, but the types need to match:

```
// since C++20 those are constexpr
template< class T >
constexpr std::complex<T> operator/( const std::complex<T>& lhs
                                   , const std::complex<T>& rhs );
template< class T >
constexpr std::complex<T> operator/( const std::complex<T>& lhs, const T& rhs);
//                                                      ^              ^
template< class T >
constexpr std::complex<T> operator/( const T& lhs, const std::complex<T>& rhs);
//                                         ^                          ^
```

while the OP mention

```
1 / matrix[1][1]
^ That's an int, not a double. 1.0 would have worked (note that 1.0f wouldn't).
```